# Kill parent of mysqld process on MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos, daemon, kill, lsof

I have a Docker machine, and I want it to be able to use port 3306. But that port is already in use.

I don't remember installing MySQL on the host machine, but I've done a lot of dumb things over the years, so there's a good chance I did. I run `brew services list` to see if it's a brew service that is blocking the port. Nope. Nothing is listed.

So I run `sudo lsof -i tcp:3306` and get the following:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  71046 _mysql   28u  IPv6 0xbdab224a8a9b989f      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
```

OK. Simple to kill, right? I run `sudo kill -QUIT 71046` and run `sudo lsof -i tcp:3306` again. Now there's a different process listening on the same port:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  71207 _mysql   28u  IPv6 0xbdab224a8a9ba41f      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
```

This process goes on as many times as I care to repeat it. Trying to run `mysql` or `mysqld` runs into a `command not found` error.

So my question: **What command do I have to run to permanently stop mysqld from respawning ad infinitum?**

(Bonus points if you can help me get rid of the setting that starts it automatically when my machine starts.)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-prefpane.html

Comment: Thanks, Bill. That did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a comment above that led you to the answer, but here's a more full explanation for the benefit of future readers:

I infer you are on MacOS because you mention `brew`. MacOS is weird because there are multiple ways to run MySQL Server. Brew is one of them, but the official download from MySQL.com uses a native package installer, and creates a launch daemon and a System Preferences pane to manage the launch daemon.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-prefpane.html

You can use the preferences pane to start and stop the launch daemon, or enable/disable its automatic startup.